# How to scatter a list in pyOpenCL?

Tags: opencl, pyopencl

lets way we have list size of 500, we have 4 kernels and we want to give 1/4 of the list to each kernel. how can we do that in OpenCL or pyOpenCl ?

I know there should probably be barrier somewhere and but how do we send the data to other kernels ? is there an exampl of Scatter in OpenCL ?

Comment: I don't know if there is built-in functionality in OpenCL for this, but you can give each kernel an offset and a quantity of elements to handle, so that kernel 1 gets (0, 125), kernel 2 gets (125, 125), kernel 3 gets (250, 125), kernel 4 gets (375, 125). Then each kernel starts at its offset and processes 125 elements from the offset, each kernel covering its own 1/4 of the list. It's more complicated if they need to communicate though.

Comment: is there any way to know how many kernels I have ?

Comment: You specify your own global sizes when you launch the kernel, that's how you can coordinate the work over multiple instances (work units, work groups, ..)